# Delete picked images one by one from gallery - flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I can able to pick the images from gallery and show it up in the UI. I have to delete the one by image after selecting. I done the UI, by showing the red cancel button for each image [image: delete icon image]. But i am unable to delete and show it up un the UI. Please help.

this is my code.

[image: Showing the picked images here]

Comment: The code you posted does not include the "delete" button, but it must be in the builder in your updated code, when the icon is tapped, call `imageFileList!.removeAt(index);`

Comment: i can able to delete the Index. But the UI is not removing the selected image.

Comment: is it wrapped with a `setState(() {})`?

Comment: Done Everything. setState also called. But UI is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Done by myself. The issue is i am using bottom sheet to add the images. To delete the images i called removeAtIndex. it works fine. The problem is the bottom sheet does not know the state of the context, so added statefull builder for the bottom sheet. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the Bottom Sheet Widget to Separate Stateful Widget and it should work.
setstate won't work inside that particular Bottom Sheet until it's separated to a Stateful Widget. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes done by adding Statefulbuilder widget to bottomsheet. It works fine. thank you.